# Structure output of 'systemctl -h' command into a list and/or dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, text-parsing

Before I spend hours trying to code this I thought I'd ask the experts to see if anyone has already accomplished this.  I've tried to do some searching but to be honest I'm not sure how to search for what I'm looking for.  So, I'll do my best to describe it here and maybe one of you can either explain a way to search for a solution to my problem or possibly even provide a solution!

I wish to gather the output of 'systemctl -h' and parse it into a Python3 list of dictionaries; with each list entry being a dictionary of the possible options listed in the Help output.

What is interesting/hard about this desired output is that there are a lot of caveats that need considered:

- Some lines in the Help output aren't options (like the first line and blank lines).
- Some lines are "headings" for a group of commands.  <-- Using this as the 'section' keyword would be a "nice to have".
- Some of the options have short-key values "-h" in addition to "--help". While other commands don't follow that format at all.
- Separation of the option's values is done using spacing/newline.  Sometimes it is a single space, sometimes multiple spaces, sometimes it is a newline along with more spaces.

I think the resulting Python list of dictionaries should have something like this as its structure:

```
help_output = [
    {'section': '<section name>',
     'options': {
         'shortcode': '<-h>',
         'longcode': '<--help or list-unit-files>',
         'description': '<blah>'
        }
    },
]
```

Alas, I lack the scripting foo to deal with all these caveats in a "clean" way.  So, instead of me hacking together some non-Pythonic garbage I would like to get some input from you all.

Thanks for your time and I hope you find my question/challenge worthy of answering.  :-)